# Filling a textbox from DropDownList Selection filled itself with CascadingDropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

I'm quite new to Visual Studio. I'm working right now on Visual Studio Express 2013 and I'm trying to fill a certain textbox in ASP.net

I'll summarize everything as best as I can (I'm not a native english speaker)

First I had this problem with the invalid postback thing. I've found only one correct solution right here : https://johanleino.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/cascadingdropdown-causes-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-error/
So, that's why I have NoValidationDropDownList instead of classical dropDownList

Also, I have 2 DropDownList using the ajax CascadingDropDown (I'm filling the second one depending on the selected value of the first one)

Here's my view :

```
<asp:TableCell>
     <asp:NoValidationDropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListVille_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="DropDownListVille" runat="server" class="ddlVille" ></asp:NoValidationDropDownList>
     <ajax:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown1" runat="server" Category="Ville"
             TargetControlID="DropDownListVille" PromptText="Non définie" LoadingText="Chargement des villes"
             ServiceMethod="AfficherVille" ServicePath="CascadingDropDown.asmx"></ajax:CascadingDropDown>
</asp:TableCell>

<asp:TableCell runat="server">
     <asp:NoValidationDropDownList ID="DropDownListRue" runat="server" class="ddlRue" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListVille_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:NoValidationDropDownList>
     <ajax:CascadingDropDown ID="ccdRegion" runat="server" Category="Rue" ParentControlID="DropDownListVille"
             TargetControlID="DropDownListRue" PromptText="Non définie" LoadingText="Chargement des rues"
             ServiceMethod="VilleRueLier" ServicePath="CascadingDropDown.asmx"></ajax:CascadingDropDown>
</asp:TableCell>

<asp:TableCell>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCP" runat="server" class="tbcp"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
```

My first dropdown have cities, second one have streets and my textbox have postcode. All data is coming from one DB using these two tables :

Ville(Id_Ville, nom_ville, code_postal)
Translated in

```
city(id_city,city_name,postcode)
```

Rue(Id_Rue,Nom_Rue)
Translated in

```
street(id_street,street_name)
```

I would like to dynamically change the postcode depending on the id of the selected city (This id is stored as a value in the dropdownlist).

See, when the city the user want is not in the db, he can select a special value of the first dropdownbox, and add a new city.

When he does that, the page display some textbox with ajax.

There, the user can add a new city with its postcode. Else, the postcode TextBox is on readonly.

But when he choose a listed city, I want the textbox to fill itself.

There's my webservice methods, linked to the cascadingDropDown :

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
private Passerelle.Passerelle passerelle = new Passerelle.Passerelle();


[WebMethod]
public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] AfficherVille(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
{


            List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> VilleDetails = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();

            ListVille listeVille = new ListVille();
            listeVille = passerelle.getListVille();

            foreach (Ville v in listeVille.List)
            {

                string idVille = v.IdVille.ToString();
                string nomVille = v.NomVille.ToString();
                VilleDetails.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(nomVille, idVille));
                Debug.WriteLine("Id Ville = " + idVille + " ----- NomVille = " + nomVille);
            }
            return VilleDetails.ToArray();
    }

[WebMethod]
public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] VilleRueLier(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
    {
    ///GET DATA FROM SQL

    ListRue listeRue = new ListRue();

    StringDictionary VilleDetails = AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues);

    int idVille = Convert.ToInt32(VilleDetails["Ville"]);

    List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> countrydetails = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();

    //Here I get the data from my table 'Rue' with the ID coming from
    listeRue = passerelle.getListRue(idVille);

            countrydetails.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue("Pas dans la liste", "-1"));

            foreach (Rue r in listeRue.list)
            {
                string idRue = r.idRue.ToString();
                string nomRue = r.nomRue.ToString();
                countrydetails.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(nomRue, idRue));
                Debug.WriteLine("Id rue = " + idRue + " ----- NomRue = " + nomRue);
            }      

            return countrydetails.ToArray();

    }

}
```

I've Tried many things... Classic events to some ajax function calls.
And I just can't figure out how to do that ...

And of course I'm following classic MVC pattern. So... No sql request in the view.

I'm not doing great with ajax.
I'm probably missing some great ajax/asp.net feature with another webMethod.

Many thanks to anyone who can help me.

And sorry for all the spelling/grammar mistakes.

I won't be able to answer for some hours (I'll come back in something like ~12 hours) If you have any questions ... I'll be there to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad.

My event were not working because **I forgot the AutoPostBack=true.**

Using UpdatePanel all around my view's items to deny refreshing the page, I've now fixed everything.